# Rails 4 devise create associated resource with 'build' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im using **gem 'devise', '~> 3.3.0'**

my *links_controller.rb*

```
def new
    @link = current_user.links.build
  end

def create
    @link = current_user.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private

def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url)
    end
```

I have add user_id to my *links* table. And already setup the relationship in User and Link model like so:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :links
end
```

But I got this error: undefined method `build' for #. What do I missed?

Comment: Did you check that you have a `current_user`?

Comment: Yes sir, because only signed in user can post new links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your `create` method is missing the `links` association:

```
def create
  @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)
  ...
```